# rospy and Tkinter - spin() and mainloop()

Tags: ros, thread, spin, rospy, multithreading

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to write a rospy node that uses Python's GUI toolkit Tkinter, problem is that rospy.spin() and top.mainloop() are both blocking calls.

I thought of starting one and setting an interrupt to start the other, like:

```
top.after(50, rospy.spin )
top.mainloop()
```

This successfully starts both loops, but once rospy.spin() starts it completely takes control from Tkinter (until I hit ctrl+c, then Tkinter resumes). What I really want is a rospy.spinOnce() that I can call on Tkinter's repaint cycle, but I gather there isn't such a thing.

Is there a good way to have both top.mainloop() and rospy.spin() running in the same thread? Or at least a work-a-round?

Edit: I found a work-a-round by forking rospy.spin() into it's own thread and protecting all my variables inside the ros callbacks with mutexes like so:

```
from threading import Thread, Lock

mutex = Lock()

def rosClbk(data) :
    mutex.aquire()
    _var = var
    mutex.release()
    # do processing on _var

def main() :
    ...
    t = Thread(target = rospy.spin )
    t.start()
    top.mainloop()
```

This makes the program a bit hard to kill (since ros no longer responds to ctrl+c), but otherwise seems to work fine. Is this too dirty? Is there a better way?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/106781/rospy-and-tkinter---spin()-and-mainloop()/) by [ounsworth](https://answers.ros.org/users/7771/ounsworth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2013-12-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If there is another blocking call that keeps your program running, there is no need to call rospy.spin(). Unlike in C++ where spin() is needed to process all the threads, in python all it does is block.

Edit:
Here's a Python/Tk node I wrote a while ago that might help: https://code.google.com/p/wu-robotics/source/browse/trunk/missouri/missouri_telepresence/demogui.py

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2013-12-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ounsworth](https://answers.ros.org/users/7771/ounsworth/) on 2013-12-04**:
Amazing, that works. Thanks.

**Comment by [Issey M](https://answers.ros.org/users/118374/issey-m/) on 2022-09-19**:
Can you please explain what you did instead? I can't manage to put Subscriber node on loop while using GUI.